# JQuery, How do i show textbox if radio button is checked after a page reloads

Tags: jquery, textbox, radio-button

I have two radio buttons, `rdPayOutstanding` and `rdPaySomeBalance`, `rdPaytOutstandingBalance` is the default radio button which is checked when the page loads, when this happens, `txtPaySomebalance` is hidden, which works fine. When `rdPaySomeBalance` is checked then `txtPaySomeBalance` should show, which works fine too..

if `txtPaySomebalace` is empty when `rdPaySomebalance` is checked, the page is not processed and reloads, which works fine too but when this happens `rdPaySomeBalance` is still checked which is what I want but and the `txtPaySomeBalance` is then hidden.

I use jQuery in hiding and showing the textbox and I only hide it if `rdPayOustandingBalance` is checked just in case the client does not have JavaScript enabled. I wish to have `txtPaySomeBalance` display when the page reloads and `rdPaySomeBalance` is still checked, can any help with the jQuery I have bellow, I have also included my CSS.

```
.txtPaySomeBalance {
    display: inline;
}

$(document).ready(function () {

    if ($('.rdOutstandingBalance').attr('checked', true)) {
        $('.txtPaySomeBalance').hide();
    }

    $('.rdOutstandingBalance').click(function () {
        $('.txtPaySomeBalance').hide();
        $('.txtPaySomeBalance').attr('disabled', true);
    });

    $('.rdPaySomeBalance').click(function () {
        $('.txtPaySomeBalance').show();
        $('.txtPaySomeBalance').removeAttr('disabled');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question text is hard to understand, I guess you want to read checked state at page load, so you can do:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Cache your results to improve readability and perfomnce
    var $rdOutstandingBalance = $('.rdOutstandingBalance');
    var $rdPaySomeBalance = $('.rdPaySomeBalance');
    var $txtPaySomeBalance = $('.txtPaySomeBalance');

    // Use change event instead of click!
    $rdOutstandingBalance.change(function () {
        if ($rdOutstandingBalance.is(':checked') == true) {
            // Chain your method calls and use prop instead of attr
            $txtPaySomeBalance.hide().prop('disabled', true);
        };
    })
    // Trigger change event to set visible state
    .change();

    // Use change event instead of click!
    $rdPaySomeBalance.change(function () {
        if ($rdPaySomeBalance.is(':checked') == true) {
            // Chain your method calls and use prop instead of attr
            $txtPaySomeBalance.show().prop('disabled', false);
        };
    });
});
```

If this doesn't help, overview your question text and, even better, create a jsfiddle to work with!